# Example of homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic compact riemannian manifolds of same dimension.

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I’m looking for an example of two riemannian manifolds that are

- compact
- of same dimension
- if possible low-dimensional
- homotopy equivalent
- but not homeomorphic

It’s proving to be rather difficult, because most "homotopy equivalent, not homeomorphic" examples I know are based on either one of the space being a lower-dimensional deformation-retract or one being complete and not the other (remove a point on the border...).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263060/simple-homotopy-equivalent-non-homeomorphic-manifolds)

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, my bad, I didn’t check MO. 
Though this isn’t a duplicate of that question, since that question doesn’t ask for compact manifolds, and is about "simple homotopy equivalence" (a notion which I didn’t know about), not regular homotopy equivalence. 
The answers to that question may help me though, thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Riemannian metrics or general topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space#Classification_of_3-dimensional_lens_spaces) are nice examples.

To quote from that article,

> The three-dimensional lens spaces $L(p;q_1)$ and $L(p;q_2)$ are:
>
> 1. Homotopy equivalent if and only if $q_1 q_2 \equiv \pm n^2$  (mod $p$) for some $n \in \mathbb N$.
> 2. Homeomorphic if and only if $q_1 \equiv \pm q_2^{\pm 1}$  (mod $p$).